# How to take the highest ordinal numbers (as strings) from array

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an array of objects of a class, and for simplification this is what my class looks like:

```
class CD {

    var artist: String!
    var title: String!
    var tracks: Int!
    var sequence: String!

}

var allCDs:[CD]= []
```

and then I have my array of a bunch of "CD" objects. I want to make a new array with *only* the latest CD for each artist, let's call it

```
var latestCDArray:[CD]= []
```

The following isn't possible, but will give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
for disc in allCDs {

    if disc.title != (any other CD.titles in array) && disc.sequence == highest {

        latestCDArray.append(disc)

    }

}
```

The real issue I have is trying to match the title to others in the array. I can't do that, I have to say allCDs[0] or allCDs[1] but that won't work with multiple titles.

Also, the "sequence" property is a string like "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "4th" so I can't sort on that.

Comment: Create a dictionary. Iterate through the array. Retrieve an entry from the dictionary using the artist as the key. If it is nil, add the cd to the dictionary with the artists as the key. If non-nil, compare the entry with the "current" cd. If the cd is later, update the cd in the dictionary. Once you are done get all,of the entries of the dictionary back into an array

Comment: A little stuck on what you're saying. There are many artists that's the issue.

Comment: That is why you use the artist name as the key for the dictionary. You only need to keep a single CD per artist. As you iterate though the original array you are keeping the current "most recent" cd in the dictionary for each artist.

Comment: The elusive twenty liter A4, gotta get me one of those :)

Comment: haha. Don't even have it anymore, but I keep using this handle. I've had a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a data structure problem rather than a coding problem.

I would organize it more like this,

```
class Artist {
    var artistName: String!
    var artistCDs = NSMutableSet()
}

class CD {
    var tracks: Int!
    var releaseDate: NSDate!
    var sequence: String!
    weak var artist: Artist?
}
```

Now you can store all your artists in their own array and easily grab the most recent cd by the releaseDate property.

Take note of the weak reference back to Artist from the CD class to make sure we don't have a retain cycle. I'm also using a NSMutableSet rather than an NSMutableArray because you most likely don't want duplicates of the same CD.

Now you can setup custom constructors in your Artist class to automatically intake the artists name and pre-made CD objects.

I apologies ahead of time for any syntactic issues, I've never written any Swift before, feel free to edit my answer.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can use structs or an NSDictionary vs. making classes.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the format of your data, there is no "easy" way to retrieve the data from the array - you need to iterate through the array and determine the "latest" cd for each artist.

My approach is below.

It creates a dictionary that is used to store the "latest" CD for each artist as we iterate the array. For each CD we check to see

- If we have seen another CD for this artist (dictionary entry for artist is/isn't null)
- If not, then just add this CD to the dictionary
- If we have, then update the dictionary if we have found a "later" CD
- At the end extract the dictionary values back to an array

Before comparing the sequence, my code strips the non-digit characters

```
var cd1=CD(artist: "Pink Floyd", title: "The Wall", tracks: 13, sequence: "1st")
var cd2=CD(artist: "Sting", title: "Dream of the Blue Turtles", tracks: 12, sequence: "1st")
var cd3=CD(artist: "Pink Floyd", title: "Wish you were here", tracks: 10, sequence: "2nd")

var allCDs:[CD]=[cd1,cd2,cd3]

var latestDictionary=Dictionary<String,CD>()

for cd in allCDs {

    if let compareCD=latestDictionary[cd.artist] {
        if let cdSequence="".join(cd.sequence.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)).toInt() {
            if let compareSequence="".join(compareCD.sequence.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)).toInt() {

                if (cdSequence > compareSequence) {
                    latestDictionary[cd.artist]=cd
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        latestDictionary[cd.artist]=cd
    }

}
var latestCDs=latestDictionary.values.array
```